# .Net CAD: cui file load

Tags: c#, .net, cad

When I load the cui file,CAD pop an error that can not find the file.

I am searching for a long time on net. But no use.Please help me.

Document doc = Application.DocumentManager.MdiActiveDocument;

```
        object oldCmdEcho = Application.GetSystemVariable("CMDECHO");

        object oldFileDia = Application.GetSystemVariable("FILEDIA");

        Application.SetSystemVariable("CMDECHO", 0);

        Application.SetSystemVariable("FILEDIA", 0);

        doc.SendStringToExecute("_.cuiload " + cuiFile + " ", false, false, false);

        doc.SendStringToExecute("(setvar \"FILEDIA\" " + oldFileDia.ToString() + ")(princ) ", false, false, false);

        doc.SendStringToExecute("(setvar \"CMDECHO\" " + oldCmdEcho.ToString() + ")(princ) ", false, false, false);
```

Ive tried multiple variations of this, but none of them seem to work. Any ideas? Please comment to help me.

Comment: Nowhere in that code do you set the value of `cuiFile`. The most likely cause of not finding a file, is that there's an issue with the file name/path. Have you debugged and confirmed the value of cuiFile is correct?

Comment: I execute all the code, It looks like it`s all right, But at the last CAD pop the error:CAD did not find the cui file.

Comment: I have debugged,and the file is exists,and the value of cuiFile is correct.

Comment: Any chance of letting us know what that value is?

Comment: the value of cuiFile is:"C:\\Program Files\\srctrunk\\srcTrunk\\srcTrunk\\Debug32\\TX_Menu.cuix"

Comment: And the File.exists(cuiFile) is true

Comment: Try wrapping cuiFile in quotes when you append it.

Comment: Sorry I am a new programmer, I do't catch your meaning.Please give me a example.

Comment: At the moment, the string you pass into your method would be `_.cuiload C:\\Program Files\\srctrunk\\srcTrunk\\srcTrunk\\Debug32\\TX_Menu.cuix ` due to the space between Program and Files, this is possibly being interpreted as 3 arguments instead of 2. I suspect what you want is `_.cuiload "C:\\Program Files\\srctrunk\\srcTrunk\\srcTrunk\\Debug32\\TX_Menu.cuix" ` So try something like `doc.SendStringToExecute("_.cuiload \"" + cuiFile + "\" ", false, false, false);` to wrap the filename as a single string.

Comment: Thank you for your answer sincerely,Through your answer,I have solved it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment, if the filename `cuiFile` includes spaces, then the string passed to `doc.SendStringToExecute` probably isn't treating your filename as a single string. So just like you have with the `setvar` calls, wrap the filename in quotes:

```
doc.SendStringToExecute("_.cuiload \"" + cuiFile + "\" ", false, false, false);
```

This should result in the filename being passed as a single string, something like : `_.cuiload "C:\\Program Files\\srctrunk\\srcTrunk\\srcTrunk\\Debug32\\TX_Menu.cuix"`